# There are any Event Properties if the a Form get blocked?

Tags: c#, authentication

I have created an application with login (using a database). Only one player can login.

I mean I am logged with username "testing" (the value `check_log` from the database will get `1`)and if I try to log-in on the different PC with the same credential will show up "Already logged".

On the `FormClosed` event, the value `check_log` will be changed in `0` and you can log in again without any problems.

The problem is that sometimes the application gets blocked (`not responding` error). Does anyone have an idea of how can change the value `check_log` in 0 before getting blocked? Because if I will close it with the task manager the value will not get changed.

Comment: First, figure out why it stops responding. The only time it should be forcefully terminated is when the user does so flagrantly and then it's their fault, not yours. Then you can address the user-did-a-bad-thing case if you need to.

Comment: @madreflection so it is not my problem, right? Do you have any idea if he on restarting the PC or laptop but not closing the app? is the same problem right?

Comment: Not what I said, at all. Something is causing the UI to stop responding and that's something you need to figure out. Fix the problem that's leading to users having to force-terminate the process.

Comment: I will, thank you:)

Comment: As to the question in the title, no, there's no such event. It would be impossible to fire an event when the thing that would fire the event cannot be reached because of the blocked state.

Comment: I got it. I thought that maybe there is one event like this. Once again thank you:)